# Create radiobutton for each element in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, button, radio-button

Can somebody help me.I'm trying to create a radiobutton for each element in array.

For example: 
`var myarray = [{name:John,name:Max,name:Oliver}{id:1,id:2,id:3}];`

And get 3 radiobuttons with id and name. How i can do that using only JS?

Comment: Is there any chance you have access to how the array is created because [ {name: John, id: 1}, {name: Max, id: 2} ] would be better

Comment: What do you want to do with the buttons? Keep them in an array to use later? Immediately add them to the DOM? Where in the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object (`{}`) is not an array and it has no order guaranteed. So you have to make an array of arrays or array of object pairs `{name: 'John', id: 1}`.

Array you have provided is invalid by the way (no coma between objects, and no quotes around names.

Example:

```js
var people = [{name: 'John', id: 1}, {name: 'Greg', id: 2}, {name: 'Susan', id: 3}];
people.forEach(function(person) {
  var label = document.createElement('label');
  label.innerHTML = person.name;
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = "radio";
  input.name = "person";
  input.value = person.id;
  document.body.appendChild(label);
  document.body.appendChild(input);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var c=0; c<=myarray.length; c++)
{
createRadioElement(myarray[c], checked , c);
}

function createRadioElement(name, checked , id) {
    var radioHtml = '<input type="radio" id="' +id+'" name="' + name + '"';
    if ( checked ) {
        radioHtml += ' checked="checked"';
    }
    radioHtml += '/>';


    divIWantToAppendTo.innerHTML += radioHtml;


}
```

**You don't need an object just make an array. The ID's can just be assigned by iterations through the array. So count 0 is the ID for the first guy and so on. Not very sophisticated but for a small program like this should be OK. I have not tested this but it should work. A loop through your array, passing a value for name, checked, and ID each time, each time it calls the function and creates a radio and adds it to the parent div, it is raw but with some fixing up it will work fine. **